# How to run Nunit test?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit

Can any one please tell me what is the result in Nunit Test?
Whether it will produce pass or fail (with error message) or it will give in which point it will produce the error and more details?
Can we store the error results in an XML file?

Answer (score 5):

The **[NUnit Documentation](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=docHome&r=2.6.1)** will probably answer most of your questions. They even provide a section on [how to run NUnit tests](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=runningTests&r=2.6.1).

Comment: Thank you Dennis for your politeness in saying RTFM ;-)